# Rails - handeling page reloads and bookmarked traffic with Ajaxish dashboard application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

This application is primarily a dashboard.  The main view elements are defined in my application.html.erb file.  Then these view elememnts are changed by the relevant controller actions.

For example; when a user clicks on the Users link(remote: true), the UsersController will append a partial into the main view-pane.  The same with the JobsController, TasksController, etc.

Im using the Push state function described in [this railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/246-ajax-history-state) to update the URL based on the relative path of the resource.  Herein lies the problem; how do I handle page reloads and traffic that has bookmarked a particular page?  The format.js portion of the respond_to block works great, but Im uncertain how to factor for format.html traffic.

thanks in advance.